# Symfony4 twig form - Customize / override form widget for radio button

Tags: forms, twig, customization, symfony4

I like to change the radio button alignment from vertical to horizontal. I knew i have to add `'form-check-inline'` into the existing code `<class = "form-check">` for it to happen.

Here are the conditions:

1. I used ***bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig*** as the base theme.
2. My FormType is :

   ```
   ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array( 
       'choices'  => array(
       'ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
       'TEACHER' => 'ROLE_TEACHER',
        ),
       'expanded' =>true,
       'multiple' =>false
        ))
        ->get('roles')
   ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
       function ($tagsAsArray) {
       // transform the array to a string
       return implode(', ', $tagsAsArray);
       },
       function ($tagsAsString) {
       // transform the string back to an array
       return explode(', ', $tagsAsString);
       }
   ))
   ```
3. I already looked into ***form_div_layout.html.twig*** but I didn't know
   which block to choose or how to customize/override it :

   - *{%- block radio_widget -%}*
   - *{%- block widget_attributes -%}*
   - *{% block attributes -%}*
4. I can arrange it use `'attr'` in twig but it create a new `<class>` instead of overriding it :

```
{{ form_widget(form.roles, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-check form-check inline'}}) }}
```

resulted :

```
<div id="task_type_transformer_roles" class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" id="task_type_transformer_roles_0" name="task_type_transformer[roles]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <label class="form-check-label required" for="task_type_transformer_roles_0">ADMIN</label>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand because as far as I can tell it already works. See https://www.codeply.com/go/aGWRU1nYkf for an example.

Comment: Yes, its worked by using 'attr' but then is it okay in terms of css best practices to have two 'form-check' classes withing that radio block/widget ? When i see the result of that, my initial thought is that is no so clean.

Comment: It might not be best, but it isn't a problem as long your layout doesn't suffer. You can however get rid of the first `form-check` class like here: https://www.codeply.com/go/Ptrdr9gQl0

Comment: Oh okay, i'll use your suggestion then, which is just add the 'form-check-inline' to the 'attr'  'class' . Thanks.